# How to change opacity suddenly without transition (without fade) using keyframes

Tags: html, css

I am working on an animation where I need to change the opacity of horizontally-aligned icons (from 0 to 1) one after another (It should appear like a gradual lit up of series of LEDs). I am using the `@keyframes` rule. But by this I am getting a transition of opacity from 0 to 1. I want a sudden change in opacity. How do I get that done only using CSS without an opacity transition effect?

HTML:

```
<core-icon style="height:20px;width:20px" id="two" class="icons" src=icons/somelogo.png></core-icon>
<core-icon style="height:20px;width:20px" id="three" class="icons" src=icons/somelogo.png></core-icon>
<core-icon style="height:20px;width:20px" id="four" class="icons" src=icons/somelogo.png></core-icon>
<core-icon style="height:20px;width:20px" id="five" class="icons" src=icons/somelogo.png></core-icon>
<core-icon style="height:20px;width:20px" id="six" class="icons" src=icons/somelogo.png></core-icon>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes two {
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes three {
    40% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes four {
    60% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes five {
    80% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes six {
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
.icons {
    opacity: 0;
}
#two {
    -webkit-animation:two linear 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 15;
}
#three {
    -webkit-animation:three linear 4s ;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 15;
}
#four {
    -webkit-animation:four linear 4s ;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 15;
}
#five {
    -webkit-animation:five linear 4s ;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 15;
}
#six {
    -webkit-animation:six linear 4s ;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 15;
}
```

Comment: Seems to me if you don't want there to be a transition then you shouldn't be using animation properties like `linear 4s`. If you just want an "invisible to visible" effect then you probably don't even need keyframes. Just set `visibility: hidden;` and then `visibility: visible;`

Comment: but them how can I do it in css at some particular point?

Comment: Probably the easiest way at this point is to use `transition-timing-function: step-end` or Leo Deng's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`animation-timing-function` can be set to `steps(1, end)`. See [**w3c spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-timing-function-property) (it's the same for animation and transition)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way more efficient or clever way of doing it, but for a quick fix you could always try to give the opacity as 0 at the percentage just before you want the icon to appear:

```
@-webkit-keyframes two {
    19% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    20%, 100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes three {
    39% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    40%, 100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
etc...
```

I also added the 100% to make sure they stay at `opacity: 1` until the end.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/mq71zoyL/

Comment: this is the fix before I know `steps()` :D